# When does Bait the Trap start working?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

Bait the Trap is a Caltrops rune which has this description:

> Become empowered while standing in the area of effect, gaining an additional 10% Critical Hit Chance with all attacks.

Is the Critical Hit bonus active before the Caltrops are triggered, after they're triggered, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at [this](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4927104037) discussion you can see that the intention of this Rune is to set the trap and use its benefits while the enemies are approaching the trap. The ability gets the buff before the trap is sprung and after as well. Until the six seconds of the trap is up you will continue to get the bonus critical hit chance.

Comment: That's excellent news. I look forward to trying it out with my Demon Hunter in a few levels (29 to be exact :-S).